# Kibana display number after comma on metric

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm actually trying to dislay all number after comma in my kibana's datatable but even with json input format, it does display as expected ...

Do you have an idea how to do this ?
[image]

[image]

Here for example I have 2.521 but in can be 0.632, or 0.194 ...

I only see 0 in Min, Max, Avg columns

In my C# code is a double and indexed as a number in Kibana index:
[image]

[image]

How to do this plz ?
Thank a lot and best regards

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that your field has been mapped as `integer` or `long`. If that's the case, 0.632 is stored as 0 and 2.521 as 2.

You need to make sure that those fields are mapped as `float` or `double` in your mapping.

PS: you cannot change the mapping type once the index has been created, you need to create a new index and reindex your data.

You need to pre-create your index with the right mapping types before sending the first document:

```
PUT webapi-myworkspace-test
{
   "mappings": {
      "properties": {
          "GraphApiResponseTime" : { 
              "type" : "double" 
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much ! Is a double in my C# code, consequently it should not be a double too in Kibana ?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. If the first document that triggered the creation of your index had a field integer value (`0`, `1`, `2`, ...) then the mapping got created as `integer`. What do you get when running this in Dev Tools `GET your-index-name` ?

Comment: I updated 2 screens in post, I don't under Dev Tools GET your-index-name, I'm a new user and I don't know many thing and how to do what you talk

Comment: In the Kibana main menu (to the left), click on "Management  > Dev Tools", then run `GET webapi-myworkspace*`, what mapping type does your `GraphApiResponseTime` field have?

Comment: thank a lot :-) I have: "GraphApiResponseTime" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                },                      How I can modify it ? Or what I need to do ?

Comment: There we go!! You need to delete your index and recreate it anew with the right mapping first. See my updated answer above

Comment: ok I predicted your response, consequently I can't do it, thanks anyway for your help

Comment: If you can't pre-create your index, you need to make sure that the first document you send contains non-integer values